# Handling union types using Graphql.NET

Tags: c#, .net, graphql

Are there any effective ways of handling union types with the [graphql.NET](https://graphql-dotnet.github.io/) library?

Consider the following graphql schema

```
type Dog {
  name: String!
  breed: String!
}

type Cat {
  name: String!
  color: String!
}

union Animal = Dog | Cat;

type SearchResults {
  results: [Animal!]!
}
```

How would the above schema translate into CLR and Graphql type?

Basically the problem is that the CLR types are autogenerated using code generator. I want to avoid having to manually map CLR to Grapql types as much as possible, in order to utilize the existing codegen tool.

I have tried using inheritance and intefaces for the clr types, but the schema is erroring.
I have also tried using the built in union type in the library, but cannot figure out how to resolve the union property.